# how to extract RDD content and put in a DataFrame using spark(scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, spark-streaming, rdd

What I am trying to do is simply to extract some information from an rdd and put it in a dataframe, using Spark (scala).

So far, what I've done is to create a streaming pipeline, connecting to a kafka topic and put the content of the topic in a RDD :

```
val kafkaParams = Map[String, Object](
      "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9092",
      "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
      "group.id" -> "test",
      "auto.offset.reset" -> "latest",
      "enable.auto.commit" -> (false: java.lang.Boolean)
    )



   .outputMode("complete")


    val topics = Array("vittorio")
    val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      ssc,
      PreferConsistent,
      Subscribe[String, String](topics, kafkaParams)
    )

    val row = stream.map(record => record.value)
    row.foreachRDD { (rdd: RDD[String], time: Time) =>


      rdd.collect.foreach(println)

      val spark = SparkSessionSingleton.getInstance(rdd.sparkContext.getConf)
      import spark.implicits._
      val DF = rdd.toDF()

      DF.show()
    }

    ssc.start()             // Start the computation
    ssc.awaitTermination()

  }

  object SparkSessionSingleton {

    @transient  private var instance: SparkSession = _

    def getInstance(sparkConf: SparkConf): SparkSession = {
      if (instance == null) {
        instance = SparkSession
          .builder
          .config(sparkConf)
          .getOrCreate()
      }
      instance
    }
  }
```

Now, the content of my rdd is :

```
{"event":"bank.legal.patch","ts":"2017-04-15T15:18:32.469+02:00","svc":"dpbank.stage.tlc-1","request":{"ts":"2017-04-15T15:18:32.993+02:00","aw":"876e6d71-47c4-40f6-8c49-5dbd7b8e246b","end_point":"/bank/v1/legal/mxHr+bhbNqEwFvXGn4l6jQ==","method":"PATCH","app_instance":"e73e93d9-e70d-4873-8f98-b00c6fe4d036-1491406011","user_agent":"Dry/1.0.st/Android/5.0.1/Sam-SM-N910C","user_id":53,"user_ip":"151.14.81.82","username":"7cV0Y62Rud3MQ==","app_id":"db2ffeac6c087712530981e9871","app_name":"DrApp"},"operation":{"scope":"mdpapp","result":{"http_status":200}},"resource":{"object_id":"mxHr+bhbNqEwFvXGn4l6jQ==","request_attributes":{"legal_user":{"sharing_id":"mxHr+bhbNqEwFvXGn4l6jQ==","ndg":"","taxcode":"IQ7hUUphxFBXnI0u2fxuCg==","status":"INCOMPLETE","residence":{"city":"CAA","address":"Via Batto 44","zipcode":"926","country_id":18,"city_id":122},"business_categories":[5],"company_name":"4Gzb+KJk1XAQ==","vat_number":"162340159"}},"response_attributes":{"legal_user":{"sharing_id":"mGn4l6jQ==","taxcode":"IQ7hFBXnI0u2fxuCg==","status":"INCOMPLETE","residence":{"city":"CATA","address":"Via Bllo 44","zipcode":"95126","country_id":128,"city_id":12203},"business_categories":[5],"company_name":"4GnU/Nczb+KJk1XAQ==","vat_number":"12960159"}}},"class":"DPAPI"}
```

and doing `val DF = rdd.toDF()` is showing :

```
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|{"event":"bank.le...|
+--------------------+
```

what I would like to achieve is a dataframe that will be populated as much as new RDD arrives from the streaming. A sort of `union` method butnot sure if is the correct way because I'm not sure all rdds will have the same schema.

for example, this is what I would like to achieve :

```
+--------------------+------------+----------+-----+
|                 _id|     user_ip|    status|_type|
+--------------------+------------+----------+-----+
|AVtJFVOUVxUyIIcAklfZ|151.14.81.82|INCOMPLETE|DPAPI|
|AVtJFVOUVxUyIIcAklfZ|151.14.81.82|INCOMPLETE|DPAPI|
+--------------------+------------+----------+-----+
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your rdd is

```
{"event":"bank.legal.patch","ts":"2017-04-15T15:18:32.469+02:00","svc":"dpbank.stage.tlc-1","request":{"ts":"2017-04-15T15:18:32.993+02:00","aw":"876e6d71-47c4-40f6-8c49-5dbd7b8e246b","end_point":"/bank/v1/legal/mxHr+bhbNqEwFvXGn4l6jQ==","method":"PATCH","app_instance":"e73e93d9-e70d-4873-8f98-b00c6fe4d036-1491406011","user_agent":"Dry/1.0.st/Android/5.0.1/Sam-SM-N910C","user_id":53,"user_ip":"151.14.81.82","username":"7cV0Y62Rud3MQ==","app_id":"db2ffeac6c087712530981e9871","app_name":"DrApp"},"operation":{"scope":"mdpapp","result":{"http_status":200}},"resource":{"object_id":"mxHr+bhbNqEwFvXGn4l6jQ==","request_attributes":{"legal_user":{"sharing_id":"mxHr+bhbNqEwFvXGn4l6jQ==","ndg":"","taxcode":"IQ7hUUphxFBXnI0u2fxuCg==","status":"INCOMPLETE","residence":{"city":"CAA","address":"Via Batto 44","zipcode":"926","country_id":18,"city_id":122},"business_categories":[5],"company_name":"4Gzb+KJk1XAQ==","vat_number":"162340159"}},"response_attributes":{"legal_user":{"sharing_id":"mGn4l6jQ==","taxcode":"IQ7hFBXnI0u2fxuCg==","status":"INCOMPLETE","residence":{"city":"CATA","address":"Via Bllo 44","zipcode":"95126","country_id":128,"city_id":12203},"business_categories":[5],"company_name":"4GnU/Nczb+KJk1XAQ==","vat_number":"12960159"}}},"class":"DPAPI"}
```

Then you can use `sqlContext`'s `read.json` to read the `rdd` to valid `dataframe` and then `select` only the needed fields as

```
val df = sqlContext.read.json(sc.parallelize(rdd))

df.select($"request.user_id"as("user_id"),
          $"request.user_ip"as("user_ip"),
          $"request.app_id"as("app_id"),
          $"resource.request_attributes.legal_user.status"as("status"),
          $"class")
  .show(false)
```

This should result the following dataframe

```
+-------+------------+---------------------------+----------+-----+
|user_id|user_ip     |app_id                     |status    |class|
+-------+------------+---------------------------+----------+-----+
|53     |151.14.81.82|db2ffeac6c087712530981e9871|INCOMPLETE|DPAPI|
+-------+------------+---------------------------+----------+-----+
```

You can get required `columns` as you wish using above method. I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can union current DataFrame with existing one:

At first, create empty DataFrame at program start:

```
val df = // here create DF with required schema
df.createOrReplaceTempView("savedDF")
```

Now in foreachRDD:

```
// here we are in foreachRDD
val df = // create DataFrame from RDD
val existingCachedDF = spark.table("savedDF") // get reference to existing DataFrame
val union = existingCachedDF.union(df)
union.createOrReplaceTempView("savedDF")
```

Good idea will be to checkpoint DataFrame in some microbatches to reduce very very long DataFrame logical plan

The other idea is to use Structured Streaming, which will replace Spark Streaming